# Passing an image as an argument to a function in python

Tags: python, opencv

How can I create a function that takes an image file (not image filename) in python. Simply, like the following:

FaceController.py

```
import cv2
from Computer_Vision import Face_Detector as FD


def detectface():
    img = cv2.imread('DSC_1902.JPG')
    FD.detect(img)


detectface()
```

Face_Detector.py

```
import cv2

def detect(img):
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    cv2.namedWindow('img',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.imwrite('messigray.png', img)
    return img
```

Error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!empty()) in cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale, file C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp, line 1698
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1698: error: (-215) !empty() in function cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale
```

Comment: Exactly like that. Which part of that code doesn't work?

Comment: Edited the question with code files and error message @Rawing

Comment: Your `img` is empty. Check file exists, and read it successfully.

Comment: Ok, so the image is empty in this case.. Also, the function call doesn't make use of the return... But I'd still like to know if there's a better way. This way seems to be copying the whole image and passing it to and from the function and it would seem expensive. How do you pass an image reference to the function, draw on the image, and have those changes realised in the outer scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a pointer pointing to the image instead of the image or the filename of the image

EDIT

```
def image_function(imagePointer):
    #DO SOMETHING WITH THE IMAGE

#HERE IS THE IMAGE POINTER
image = open('your_image.png')

#CALLING THE FUNCTION
image_function(image)
```

Sorry, I don't know opencv so I can not help in your code :(

Answer (score 0):

You can actually pass the image as a tensor.
with cv2.imread() and torch.
Which is easy, useful.

short answer:
load with cv2.imread()
transform to tensor with
img = torch.Tensor(img)/255.

That works for my application.
Yours might be a little different.

Code answer:

```
from Computer_Vision import Face_Detector as FD

def detectface():
  import cv2 
  import torch
  
  folder = r"This Folder/"
  image_file = folder+"image.png"
  # or 
  # file = r"image.png"
  # image_file = os.path.join(folder, file)
  img = imread(image_file)
  
  img = torch.Tensor(img)/255. # THE KEY LINE HERE.

   FDdetect(img):
     """Do stuff with object detection..."""
     result = 
     return result
```